# Authentification failure for PostgreSQL server (9.3)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin, password

I can currently not connect to my Postgresql server (9.3) from pgadmin (Running on Ubuntu 14.04). The server according to pg_lsclusters is on port 5433.

```
    Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
    9.1 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log
    9.3 main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log
```

I can connect to the 9.1 server with pgadmin, but when I try to access the 9.3 server I get the error that the password can't be authenticated:

```
    An error has occurred:

    Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  Passwort-Authentifizierung für Benutzer „postgres“ fehlgeschlagen
    FATAL:  Passwort-Authentifizierung für Benutzer „postgres“ fehlgeschlagen
```

The 9.1 server has the following lines in pg_hba.conf:

```
    # Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
    local   all             postgres                                peer

    # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

    # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
    local   all             all                                     peer
    # IPv4 local connections:
    host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
    # IPv6 local connections:
    host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
    # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
    # replication privilege.
    #local   replication     postgres                                peer
    #host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
    #host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

and the 9.3 server has the following in the pg_hba.conf:

```
    # Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
    local   all             postgres                                md5

    # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

    # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
    local   all             all                                     md5
    # IPv4 local connections:
    host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
    # IPv6 local connections:
    host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
    # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
    # replication privilege.
    #local   replication     postgres                                peer
    #host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
    #host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

The difference is the "peer" or "md5" in the first two active lines. I am going to try switching those to peer next. Am I on the right track to a solution? (Edit: No, this did not help).

## Password

I tried changing the default password of the server using:

```
    $ sudo -u postgres psql
    psql (9.3.4, Server 9.1.13)

    postgres=#  \password
```

I have no idea why this didn't work. Maybe the command only affects the 9.1 server and not the 9.3 server (Hopefully I can kill the old one now and properly set up the 9.3 server).

## Related questions:

-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664074/getting-error-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres-when-trying-to-ge

-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942485/psql-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres?rq=1

Comment: How do you connect with pgadmin? Are you using the socket or are you using the localhost/127.0.0.1?

Comment: I tried both leaving the "Host"-field in pgadmin empty, and typing in "localhost". Both entries don't work.

Comment: "*Passwort-Authentifizierung für Benutzer "postgres" fehlgeschlagen*" sounds as if you simply supplied a wrong password

Comment: Yes, I should mention that. The default password did not work and setting the password to something else also didn't work (Using sudo -u postgres psql).

Comment: If you forgot the password you need to switch to `trust` mode, then login using the `postgres` super user (no need for a `sudo`, just use `psql -U postgres`) change the password, then change `trust` back to `md5`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I will open a new question for this, as I am encountering more problems.

Answer (score 2):

I found a temporary solution to my problem. I edited the **pg_hba.conf** of the 9.3 server to say **trust** in the first two active lines. And after restarting (*sudo service postgresql restart*) I can connect to the server again using pgadmin. The downside is that the server might now not be password protected (*I will open a separate question if I encounter any problems with that*).

```
    # Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
    local   all             postgres                                trust

    # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

    # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
    local   all             all                                     trust
    # IPv4 local connections:
    host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
    # IPv6 local connections:
    host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
    # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
    # replication privilege.
    #local   replication     postgres                                peer
    #host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
    #host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: Well, you don't need to open a new question for: it is ;) Every local user can now connect without any password.