# Setting password for 9.3 PostgreSQL server

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin

I currently have a 9.3 server running (on Ubuntu 14.04) with "trust" set as the authentification method in **pg_hba.conf**. How can I set the password again. In pgadmin the server currently doesn't allow me to access the console (The PSQL console closes immediately after I open it).

I have the feeling that setting the password using

```
     $ sudo -u postgres psql
```

changes the password of a parallel running 9.1 server.

Using

```
     psql -U postgres
```

gives an error saying

```
   psql: FATAL:  Peer-Authentifizierung für Benutzer »postgres« fehlgeschlagen
```

(peer authentification for user postgres failed)

## pg_hba.conf

```
    # Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
    local   all             postgres                                trust

    # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

    # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
    local   all             all                                     trust
    # IPv4 local connections:
    host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
    # IPv6 local connections:
    host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
    # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
    # replication privilege.
    #local   replication     postgres                                peer
    #host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
    #host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

## Setting password in pgadmin

After setting the password for the postgres user (1), the ENCRYPTED PASSWORD appears in pgadmin (2), but **psql -U postgres** still fails.

[image]

Previous question:

- [Authentification failure for PostgreSQL server (9.3)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64786/authentification-failure-for-postgresql-server-9-3)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - pinging

Comment: you can't ping a user like that.

Answer (score 0):

If your pg_hba.conf is set correctly and you're sure about your password, and you're still getting issues related to "peer authentication" failed, you probably need to reload your postgresql instance

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql reload 9.3
```

should reload your settings and allow you to use the password. Hope that helps. =)